# Como me puedo conectar a una Base de datos remota con MONGOSH?

Tags: mongodb

Estoy queriendome conectar a la base de datos remota de Covid 19, por lo que entendi me logre conectarme con la consola de windows, pero hay alguna forma de hacerlo con `MONGOSH`?

Este es el link:

```
mongodb+srv://readonly:readonly@covid-19.hip2i.mongodb.net/covid19
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿No funciona ejecutar el comando `mongosh "mongodb+srv://readonly:readonly@covid-19.hip2i.mongodb.net/covid19~"`? A mi [me funciona](https://ibb.co/7WDQyvY).

Comment: Me sale el error `Error: clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.`